# Elastic Search - Fetch only certain field across all indexes

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

I have hundreds of indexes and I want to fetch only a given field from every record under these indexes. I can do the following

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/cms-2016-03-30/job/_search?pretty=true&field=CMSDataset'
```

This unfortunately returns a lot of things I don't want and also doesn't give me all the records (~10^6).

Also, there are many cms-* style indexes, and I want to parse through all of them and get **only** this field. How do I do this?

Comment: Maybe it is just a typo? Try [fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) instead of field

Comment: Tried it. Still not what I am looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you have field named `CMSDataset` ?

Comment: Can you post your mapping and settings?

Comment: Sorry. I mis-typed. I should have run the command with "fields" using DESIRED_CMSDataset instead. That said, the _source form in the answers works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [source filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-source-filtering.html) instead of `fields` (which is deprecated)

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/cms-2016-03-30/job/_search?pretty=true&_source=CMSDataset'
                                                                            ^
                                                                            |
                                                                       change this
```

From the [official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html):

> The fields parameter is about fields that are explicitly marked as stored in the mapping, which is off by default and generally not recommended. Use source filtering instead to select subsets of the original source document to be returned.

**UPDATE**

You can use the size parameter (e.g. 100) in order to return more records (by default it's 10) and then simply use `*` as the index name:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/*/_search?pretty=true&size=100&_source=CMSDataset'
```

Comment: It still doesn't give the answer to why he didn't get any data

Comment: I mentioned fields is deprecated, I've added the link + the official explanation.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer if you can explain (or declared impossible) how to get all the records from all the indexes. Currently this only returns 10 records.